# Formatting line breaks in python strings

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string:

```
f = open("file.txt", r)
message = f.read()

print message
>>> "To: email\ntitle: add title here\nDescription: whatever here\n"
```

I can split the string by doing:

```
f_email, f_title, f_description, blank = message.split('\n')
```

But the problem arises when I have the message like this:

```
"To: email\ntitle: add title here\nDescription: first line\nSecond line\nthirdline\n"
```

When I split the string it splits the description as well. I have tried:

```
f_email, f_title, f_description, blank = message.split('\n',4)
```

But that obviously returns ValueError because it is splitting more 4 \n's.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If the 'To' and 'title' are always on their own line with no internal linebreaks, you could just split on `\n`, where the first element is email, second title, and do `'\n'.join( therest )` for the body?

Comment: Maybe you can just read the file line by line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `.split('\n')` you return a list. Rather than assign the variables when you split, you can pull them out of the list:

```
tokens = message.split('\n')
f_email = tokens[0]
f_title = tokens[1]
f_description = tokens[2]
```

This can be made less fragile by checking the size of the list. If you know it needs at least three elements, you can:

```
assert(len(tokens)>=3)
```

Another way to get around this is to wrap the thing up in a `try/except` block:

```
tokens = message.split('\n')
try:  
    f_description = tokens[2]
except:
    f_description = None
```

That way you can handle the case for a shorter list the exact way you like!

Answer (score 4):

@Hooked gave a good answer for Python2.
Since in Python3 `*` works also for tuple unpacking, you can do:

```
f_email, f_title, *f_description = tokens
```

The details are in [PEP 3132](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

Comment: Arg, I was just about to post this ;) +1, it's the nice solution for 3.x users.

Comment: for completeness, you can join the elements of f_description with '\n's to regain the original description string.

Comment: Also, the solution in this spirit, can be adapted to Python2, by passing `*tokens` to a method which does the processing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the text as a whole, and are not under 3.x to use the nice splat unpacking, you can simply do it like this:

```
email = None
title = None
description = ""
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    for number, line in enumerate(f):
       if number == 0:
           email = line.strip()
       elif number == 1:
           title = line.strip()
       else:
           description += line
```

Comment: +1: Thank you very helpful but the code can look a bit long if I have a very long string from a file.

Answer (score 1):

When you use message.split('\n', 2) you get three parts: first line, second line and remaining lines in one.

Use this form:

```
f = open("file.txt")  
f_email, f_title, f_description = f.read.split('\n', 2)  
f.close()
```

Or this:

```
f = open("file.txt")  
f_email = f.readline()  
f_title = f.readline()  
f_description = f.read()  
f.close()
```